# TextLocal.in SMS Api for new order Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, sms-gateway

I am using the following API code to send an SMS when a new order is placed, the SMS API code is working to send SMS... Placed at the end of child theme in functions.php file... all is updated(WordPress 5.9.3 and woo-commerce 6.4 with PHP 8.0)

2 Issues:

1. The $order_id and $order_date do not populate in the given variables and the SMS is received as is with the 2 variables.
2. When the order is placed by a customer this code is triggered and SMS is received even when the payment is not made and the order status in the backend is showing pending payment.

Tried the following:

1. For the 1st issue I changed the message variable to '$order_id' or '.$order_id.' but it did not work and wp crashed so had to keep plain $order_id...
2. For the 2nd issue, I changed the hook to 'woocommerce_order_status_processing' but this code does not work for a new order.

Documentation: https://www.textlocal.in/free-developer-sms-api/

Any suggestions to tweak the code so both the problems are solved?

Thanks

```
// Sending SMS to customers on new orders
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order', 10, 3);
function custom_msg_customer_process_order ($order_id) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_date = $order->get_date_created();
$billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

$apiKey = urlencode('apikey');

// Message details
$numbers = array($billing_phone,91xxxxxxxxxx);
$sender = urlencode('TXTCL');
$message = rawurlencode('Thank you for buying from us, a Wellness product. Your order number $order_id Dated $order_date is confirmed.');

$numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

// Prepare data for POST request
$data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process your response here
echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know much about the texting API (and I sure hope your customers are opting in to text updates!), what I think is happening is that `new WC_Order` never reads your data from the database. How you should get a new order object is `wc_get_order()`. However, the `woocommerce_new_order` hook passes along the [`$order` object as the 2nd parameter](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L173)

So if we make sure our callback is expecting a second parameter there's no need to re-instantiate the order object.

As for part 2, `woocommerce_new_order` will fire when the order is saved to the DB and it doesn't matter what the order status is. Instead, I think we can use [`woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php#L373%60) which is what the new order email uses.

```
/**
 * Sending SMS to customers on new orders.
 * 
 * @param int $order_id The order ID. *
 * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
 */
function custom_msg_customer_process_order( $order_id, $order ) {

    $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
    $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

    $apiKey = urlencode('apikey');

    // Message details
    $numbers = array($billing_phone,91xxxxxxxxxx);
    $sender = urlencode('TXTCL');

    // Use sprintf() to replace placeholders with values.
    $message = rawurlencode( sprintf( 'Thank you for buying from us, a Wellness product. Your order number %s Dated %s is confirmed.', $order_id, $order_date ) );

    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order', 10, 2 );
```

**Alternative**

The above depends on your gateway setting the order to `processing`. If it does not (or if it wasn't initially `pending`) then it may not fire... since it only fires on the transition from `pending` to `processing`. A better hook might actually be [`woocommerce_payment_complete`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php#L122). But note that in source, it only passes 1 parameter to its callbacks... the `$order_id` (similar to the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook does). Therefore the code snippet would need to be adjusted to expect only a single parameter:

```
/**
 * Sending SMS to customers on new orders.
 * 
 * @param int $order_id The order ID. *
 */
function custom_msg_customer_process_order( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Quit early if not a valid order.
    if ( ! $order ) {
         return;
    }

    $order_date = wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() );
    $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

    $apiKey = urlencode('apikey');

    // Message details
    $numbers = array($billing_phone,91xxxxxxxxxx);
    $sender = urlencode('TXTCL');
    
    // Use sprintf() to replace placeholders with values.
    $message = rawurlencode( sprintf( 'Thank you for buying from us, a Wellness product. Your order number %s Dated %s is confirmed.', $order_id, $order_date ) ) );

    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
}
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order' );
```

Comment: Hi it does not work with 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing' the code does not trigger when using this action so I had to use 'woocommerce_thankyou', result of this is I got the error in the error log and the sms was not received...

[16-Apr-2022 05:11:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function custom_msg_customer_process_order(), 1 passed in /wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307 and exactly 2 expected in /wordpress/wp-content/themes/kadence/functions.php:94

Comment: This assumes your gateway sets the order to `processing` when payment is completed. It fires for me and writes some data in the log. You cannot have `function custom_msg_customer_process_order( $order_id, $order )` expecting 2 parameters when the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook only passes one... [the `$order_id`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php#L80)

Comment: Hi, I changed the code but unfortunately, it is still not working the values are not populating in the message with the order number and date... the SMS is still the same as is in the message... The code is working perfectly when a new order comes in... the 2nd issue I am not concerned about now... so, the only issue is the 1st, I want the order number and date to be in the message and not the variables...

Comment: Hi @Rds in my tests `$order_date = $order->get_date_created();
    $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();` are populated just fine. I will admit that I didn't look too closely at the SMS message variables since I cannot test the SMS portion. However, I can see that your `$message` does not use proper string replacement. so `$message` is being considered as a string. See the edit... and also the manual for [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking, It's working! received the data populated in those 2 variables, thank you so much... Now Received as: Thank you for buying from us, a Wellness product. Your order number 1218 Dated 2022-04-21T15:54:21+05:30 is confirmed. Just a small issue, the date populated is too long(see how it is) can we make it smaller, like just the date???

Comment: `$order->get_date_created()` must return the MySQL formatted date that is saved in the database. You probably need PHP's ['date()'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format. Example: `date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order_date ) )`

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking, it is all working now (used `wc_format_datetime()`) changed the line from 
`$order_date = $order->get_date_created();`
To
`$order_date = wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() );`
After this change, the date came proper in the format as selected in settings-> general instead of formatting in the code... Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/jkG0qD.jpg New SMS received as Thank you for buying from us, a Wellness product. Your order number 1224 Dated 23/04/2022 is confirmed. I Thank you so much for all the effort, Hope this helps others who would face the same problem.

Comment: Great... glad that's working. Please mark this as the answer.